# How to delete data of shared-preferences from singleton in flutter?

Tags: flutter, singleton, static-methods

I make one file to shared preferences to store data in it from my app. It's work fine.But now I want to delete data from store as button log-out for user. So if user click button of log-out data will be clear from shared preferences file. How I can do it from different class?

```
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

class MyPreferences{

  static const  USER = "user";
  static const  PASSWORD = "password";

  static final MyPreferences instance = MyPreferences._internal();


  //Campos a manejar
  SharedPreferences _sharedPreferences;
  String user = "";
  String password = "";

  MyPreferences._internal(){

  }

  factory MyPreferences()=>instance;

  Future<SharedPreferences> get preferences async{
    if(_sharedPreferences != null){
      return _sharedPreferences;
    }else{
      _sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
      user = _sharedPreferences.getString(USER);
      password = _sharedPreferences.getString(PASSWORD);
      return _sharedPreferences;

    }

  }
  Future<bool> commit() async {
    await _sharedPreferences.setString(USER, user);
    await _sharedPreferences.setString(PASSWORD, password);
  }

  Future<MyPreferences> init() async{
    _sharedPreferences = await preferences;
    return this;
  }


}
```

Comment: one way you can proceed is just set the username and password to null or some empty string while logging out and checking everytime the app start weather the username and password is not null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define your shared preference manager class as a `singleton` as given,

```dart
class SharedPreferenceManager{
  static final SharedPreferenceManager _singleton = new SharedPreferenceManager._internal();

  factory SharedPreferenceManager() {
    return _singleton;
  }
  SharedPreferenceManager._internal() {
    ... // initialization logic here
  }
  ... // rest of the class
}
```

By this, you can create and access the single, reusable instance of that class. You can define a static method in the class which will be accessible from outside. As the static method can have access to only static data members, You should define the `sharedPrefernece` member variable as static. Here is how you can clear all the data.

```dart
static Future<bool> clearSharedPrefs(){
    SharedPreferences preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    await preferences.clear();
}
```

After this, you'll be able to call this method from any class, just as `SharedPreferenceManager.clearSharedPrefs()`.

It's a good practice to follow the singleton pattern for database, network and shared preference related tasks.

Here is the code you should go with.

```dart
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

class MyPreferences{

  static const  USER = "user";
  static const  PASSWORD = "password";

  static final MyPreferences instance = MyPreferences._internal();

  static SharedPreferences _sharedPreferences;
  String user = "";
  String password = "";

  MyPreferences._internal(){}

  factory MyPreferences()=>instance;

  Future<SharedPreferences> get preferences async{
    if(_sharedPreferences != null){
      return _sharedPreferences;
    }else{
      _sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
      user = _sharedPreferences.getString(USER);
      password = _sharedPreferences.getString(PASSWORD);
      return _sharedPreferences;
    }
  }

  Future<bool> commit() async {
    await _sharedPreferences.setString(USER, user);
    await _sharedPreferences.setString(PASSWORD, password);
  }

  Future<MyPreferences> init() async{
    _sharedPreferences = await preferences;
    return this;
  }

  static Future<bool> clearPreference() async{
     if(_sharedPreferences){
         _sharedPreferences.clear();
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: Ah, You can use the singleton pattern as given. As you have java background you must be aware that the static methods can be accessed outside of class just by using the class name. a static method can only access the static member variables similar to java :)

Comment: Yes bro I was use it in java some time as intent to pass data to other class

Answer (score 0):

You can use `remove` or `clear` on shared preferences.

```dart
SharedPreferences preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
preferences.clear();
// OR
preferences.remove("MY KEY HERE");
```

Comment: Hi brother .. I try like that but it's doesn't work with me